Should I Adjust Lint Rules like final for Local Variables and Quote Styles in Flutter?
In my Flutter project, I heavily use final for local variables to ensure immutability and maintain structure. However, the SonarQube scan flags this as an issue. Similarly, my project consistently uses single quotes (') for package imports, but lint rules prefer double quotes.
Should I adjust these rules in my analysis_options.yaml to fit my project needs, or is it better to strictly follow the default guidelines? I’d appreciate insights from Flutter experts on balancing lint rules with practical project requirements.
Tried to add lint rule to allow the final for local variable as i want confirmation is it a valid practice as if needed structure against lint rule can be updated as according to project structure or use strict rules defined.

is ok in adjusting the rules to analisys_options
Understand that every language,framework or tool has in your deocumentation a good practice guide to follow,attention that many of these practices are not 'Murturing' but rather a way to secure consistency, this is good because then SDKs and other programs can treat of your project efficiently based on rules already defined
take a look here you will see more reasons why it is interesting to follow the flutter lint rules
"Some guidelines describe an exception where the rule does not apply. When listed, the exceptions may not be exhaustive—you might still need to use your judgement on other cases."

My project code architecture contains the final declaration for local variables and my code is functional but in sonar flutter plugin after scanning seeing this as issue. As i want  my code architecture shouldn't be changed but this issue should be resolved in sonar scan. So that is why I am confirming if needed adding any supportive rule to override any existing rule is valid approach or not?

is a valid approach,go ahead
